# Alternative to manually creating each node in a game tree? (java)

Tags: java, nodes

I'm working on building a partial tree for Monte Carlo Search Tree, I have my node class and it contains things like the game board, who's turn it is, and a list of Nodes for the children nodes. The node constructor takes in a game board and the depth (of the tree) as the parameters. For the root node I call it like so:

```
Node root = new Node(this.quartoBoard, currentDepth);
```

(Where depth is 0) that works fine, however, when depth 1, which will be the children of the root node needs to contain 32 nodes. I naively tried this:

```
        for(int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_PIECES; i++) {
            Node c1 = new Node(this.quartoBoard, currentDepth);
            c1.setParent(root);
            childrenList1.add(c1);
        }
```

And realized that Nodes can not be created in a for loop like this. Is there an alternative to declaring each node one at a time like so:

```
Node child1 = new Node(this.quartoBoard, currentDepth);
Node child2 = new Node(this.quartoBoard, currentDepth);
```

I need to create over 800 nodes and I feel like there is a better way to do it, I just am drawing blanks on how. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: what is the reason you can not create the nodes inside the loop?

Comment: Because the variables in the loop are local to it, so once the loop ends the node will no longer exist

Comment: childrenList1 is defined outside the loop and it will have references to the children, because you are adding the nodes to the list

Comment: when you build a tree, you can use recursion to build the levels of the tree in an easy simple code. do you know how to do that?

Comment: Hmm okay thank you, in my constructor for my Node class I have a counter that keeps track of the number of nodes created and it only shows 2 nodes when I call it. And those are the two nodes I manually create, but maybe I have an issue with the counter. Thank you for the reply, I'll take a closer look at testing it

Comment: ok you are welcome, if you get stuck you can provide your code in the question, so we can help

Comment: I can't find a way to use recursion for a partial game tree, I have done it for binary search trees but I am not sure how to do it for a tree with this structure. each of these 32 children nodes has 25 of their own children nodes, it gets huge really quick.